# Firefox log message printing when I open the firefox-bin file from terminal?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, firefox, logging, terminal

On my Ubuntu (20.04) machine I have a bash script that runs firefox automatically (helps me practice bash and using the terminal). It works fine but whenever I run the command from the terminal and the window opens I inevitably get the same log message outputted to the terminal over and over again:

```
###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

I've looked into the message and it seems to be a common firefox error. I'm just wondering if anyone has any quick fixes for preventing it from being printed to the terminal over and over again?

The code for the script can be found [here](https://github.com/orbitalhybridization/ffox/).

Thanks!

Orbital

Comment: You are running firefox in background but it's still connected to stdout.
The usual workaround for this is to redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null (` /opt/firefox/firefox-bin $1 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
`). Firefox has also -MOZ_LOG_FILE but for some reason doesn't seem to work with /dev/null.

Comment: Hi Sorin, thank you for the great solution! It works like a charm, and I learned a little bit about how processes connect to stdout and stderr. Very cool, I appreciate it! :-)